# How do I add a library (android-support-v7-appcompat) in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-support-library

I created a project, copied the resource files in the project, library, added it to the project structure, prescribed style `Theme.AppCompat`.
Compiled without errors, but when you start the relegation Exception:

```
08-03 00:50:00.406: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4055): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:98)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
        at com.example.SampleMetrRost.CentralActivity.onCreate(CentralActivity.java:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4636)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1051)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1924)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1985)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4476)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:816)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:583)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Help me, please. Spent all day today.

Comment: Ran into the same problem, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/18916738/183575 for a simple and clean way to solve it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIzgaMiyKoM

Answer (score 85, accepted):

### Without Gradle ([Click here for the Gradle solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18026612/116938))

1. [Create a support library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).
2. Import your library project to Intellij from Eclipse project (this step only applies if you created your library in Eclipse).
3. Right click on module and choose Open Module Settings.
4. Setup libraries of v7 jar file
   [image: Setup libraries of v7 jar file]
5. Setup library module of v7 
   [image: Setup library module of v7]
6. Setup app module dependency of v7 library module
   [image: Setup app module dependency of v7 library module]

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how you get to step 5? I'd be very grateful... Thanks!

Comment: @SiGanteng Step 5 is actually done automatically when you perform step 1 & 2

Answer (score 118):

### Using Gradle

If you are using Gradle, you can add it as a `compile` dependency.

Instructions

1. Make sure you have the `Android Support Repository` SDK package installed. Android Studio automatically recognizes this repository during the build process (not sure about plain IntelliJ).

   [image: Android Support Repository]
2. Add the dependency to `{project}/build.gradle`

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
   }
   ```
3. Click the `Sync Project with Gradle Files` button.

**EDIT**: Looks like these same instructions are on the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) under  `Adding libraries with resources -> Using Android Studio`.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not use Gradle.
I do not have Android Studio
I program in the IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: I mostly added this in case someone else found your question and used Gradle. This should work if someone has the Android plugins for IntelliJ and uses Gradle.

Comment: Thanks for adding. Have you ever added the support library to a android library project and tried to run a app depending on the android library project? I seem to always get a "already added" exception while compiling. Not sure why - it is only added on the library project.

Comment: For the record: it works the same way with plain IntelliJ. You'll just need to "Make project" once you finish installing the "Android Support Repository".

Comment: This does not work. You still need to add it as a library in order to reference the references. I dont know why. It's been confusing me all day too.

Comment: What do you mean "reference the references"? Are you talking about attaching documentation to a jar or Android Library?

Comment: @Eggman87 I know this is late, but try `com.android.support:support-v4:+` in your library project. This will tell it to use whatever version the project using it provides.

Comment: @AustynMahoney thanks! The issue was fixed with a later release of AS/Gradle.

Comment: @Eggman87 Actually as this '+' in the end instead of version worked for me now.. The error resurfaced bunch of times randomly, but now with this it works. Thanks for this, stopped wasting my time.

Answer (score 10):

**Using Maven**

First of all you should install android libraries to your local maven repository using [Maven Android SDK Deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer)

Then you can add dependency to your pom like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
        <version>${compatibility.version}</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
        <version>${compatibility.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: The Deployer didn't work for me. Instead I followed these steps: 1) Goto ANDROID_HOME\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat 2) Create a zip file of the entire library and call it appcompat.apklib 3) Open cmd in this location and type "mvn install:install-file -Dfile=appcompat.apklib -DgroupId=com.google.android -DartifactId=support-v7-appcompat -Dversion=r7 -Dpackaging=apklib" 4) Goto /libs 5) Type "mvn install:install-file -Dfile=android-support-v7-appcompat.jar -DgroupId=com.google.android -DartifactId=support-v7-appcompat -Dversion=r7 -Dpackaging=jar" 6) Add the appropriate dependencies

Comment: This was usefull as well: https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkLib

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution:

1. Copy&paste $ANDROID_SDK/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat to your project ROOT
2. Open "Project Structure" on Intellij, click "Modules" on "Project Settings", then click "appcompat"->"android', make sure "Library Module" checkbox is checked.
3. click "YOUR-PROJECT_NAME" under "appcompat", remove "android-support-v4" and "android-support-v7-compat"; ensure the checkbox before "appcompat" is checked. And, click "ok" to close "Project Structure" dialogue.
4. back to the mainwindow, click "appcompat"->"libs" on the top-left project area. Right-click on "android-support-v4", select menuitem "Add as library", change "Add to Module" to "Your-project". Same with "android-support-v7-compat".

After doing above, intellij should be able to correctly find the android-support-XXXX modules.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 4):

Another yet simple solution is to paste these line into the build.gradle file

```
dependencies {

    //import of gridlayout
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to ask for the latest version of appcompat. Instead, use this: 

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:{targetSdkVersion}.+'

Answer (score 3):

Another solution for **maven** (and a better solution, for me at least) is to use the maven repository included in the local android SDK. To do this, just add a new repository into your pom pointing at the local android SDK:

```
<repository>
    <id>android-support</id>
    <url>file://${env.ANDROID_HOME}/extras/android/m2repository</url>
</repository>
```

After adding this repository you can add the standard Google dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
    <artifactId>support-v13</artifactId>
    <version>${support-v13.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
    <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
    <version>${appcompat-v7.version}</version>
    <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

### As a Library Project

You should add the resources in a library project as per http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

> Section > Adding libraries with resources

You then add the `android-support-v7-appcompat` library in your workspace and then add it as a reference to your app project.

Defining all the resources in your app project will also work (but there are a lot of definitions to add and you have missed some of them), and it is not the recommended approach.

Comment: Please also note, that if you defining all resources from appcompat project to your project, you should check that R.java generated file should be in `android.support.v7.appcompat` package. Otherwise, resources won't be visible by android-support-v7-appcompat.jar

Comment: I am using IDEA, tell me, please, how to add a library with resources.
Resources he sees compile without errors, but when you start getting out the error

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, it is very similar to the previous one:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>support-v7</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${android.home}/support/v7/appcompat/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar</systemPath>
        <version>19.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Where {android.home} is the root directory of the Android SDK and it uses *systemPath* instead of *repository*.

Comment: support-v7 is not just a simple jar file

Answer (score 0):

As an update to [Austyn Mahoney's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18026612/7311767), configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.

It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see [here](http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html).