# Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar - No resource found

Tags: java, android, adt

How to use properly Android Support Library because i have this error in my manifest file:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name 
(at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar').
AndroidManifest.xml /ttab   line 39 Android AAPT Problem
```

My friend did this implementing for me previously on other computer, now i have to do this alone. Please help me:)

I am using ADT

My styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
     <!-- theme customizations here. -->
    </style>


    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
      <!-- theme customizations here. -->
    </style>


</resources>
```

Comment: Import the AppCompat Library project (support lib v7) in your eclipse.
See this - http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: i did this before, but the problem has not been solved

Comment: Have you added the appcompat project as a library project in your app?

Comment: i have some, i have done this using official instructions from docs

Comment: 2 things. 1.) Do you have your appcompat project marked as library project? If not then right click on appcompat in eclipse, selecte android and check isLibrary.
2.) Right click on your porject, add the appcompat as a library project to it and do a clean build.
Thats All.. All the necessary styles are contained in the appcompat project(appcompat/res/values/styles)..

Comment: 1) yes 2) i did exacly as you wrote me but i have something like that:  http://s14.postimg.org/dnh3n9f75/android.jpg

Comment: yes, exactly. remove the library app from there because it is incorrectly referenced. Remove it and add again.

Comment: but before that import it into eclispe

Comment: please explain me: i have to remove my library project or only library refference?

Comment: remove the library reference and add it again. The 'x' mark in red color would become a 'check' mark if it is correctly referenced.

Comment: check this image with a green check mark - http://imagebin.org/268317

Comment: i made it, but no result... i have even added again my library project in order to do this what you wrote above...

Comment: Heh masters :)

I have solved this issue. Problem was that my appcompact library projest has been located in different location. On importing I have to check 
"Copy project into workspace" thats all!

Comment: Here is the right and illistrated answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025942/how-do-i-add-a-library-android-support-v7-appcompat-in-intellij-idea

Answer (score 16):

In "android-support-v7-appcompat" project:

- Delete “android-support-v7-appcompat” from Package explorer.
- Import again and check “Copy into workspace”
- In Properties -> Android -> in Project build target, uncheck Android 2.2 and check Android 4.1.2
- In Java build path, uncheck if you have any .jar library, and uncheck the Dependences

In other hand, the project that uses “android-support-v7-appcompat”:

- In Properties -> Android add the library, but uncheck "IsLibrary”.
- In Android -> Project build tarjet check Android 4.0.
- In "Java Build Path" -> Order and Export -> Unchecked the .jar library
- Finally do a “Project -> Clean” both projects

Comment: I tried a lot of things from other similar questions before I got here,  the problem was the export of the dependencies, didn't know that the libraries don't  have to export that things. Thank you, you saved my day! :) Gracias broder, te pasaste!

Comment: It would be great to specify how to import the file in in the first place - when I click on "import" I don't have the option to import a jar.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Gradle, then you have a problem with the latest version of the compatibility library.

If you have the following in your `build.gradle` file with a `'+'` at the end:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

then it may be grabbing a later version of the library than you want.

Changing the dependency to:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0+'
}
```

may fix your problem.

Comment: How if i not use build.gradle  ? My project have AndroidManifest.xml only

Answer (score 6):

Could you please try

```
android:theme="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

instead of

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your app dependencies file check if you have the dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompatv[anything here]
```

or

```
implement 'com.android.support:appcompat[anything here]
```

delete or comment them out, click on the "lightbulb" for auto-suggestions and choose add a library dependency. 
[clicking on the autofillbulb for appcompat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA8a6.png)

Scroll the options for the first version of appcompat. The library will be added below the list of dependencies. Rebuild the app or invalidate caches and restart

In one case this has not worked and going to the folder containing the project, deleting the .gradle file and restarting Android Studio has worked. Got from Sneh Pandya's answer in https://reformatcode.com/code/android/error-while-gradle-sync

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your project directory (or to Project View)
2. Find and open .idea directory
3. Remove caches and libraries directories <-- this is essential
4. Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: This does not help