# No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

I have added `android-support-v7-appcompat` and `appcompat_v7` to the project explorer. And also added the `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` to the build path.

But again I'm getting this

```
No resource found - Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar!
```

[image: Screenshot of eclipse package explorer]

How to fix this?

Comment: [Have you added `android-support-v7-appcompat` as the project library?](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar - No resource found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364682/theme-appcompat-light-darkactionbar-no-resource-found)

Comment: Refer to the link, it will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/44326032/1252158

Answer (score 7):

For me the solution involved recreating Android's v7 application compatibility (appcompat) support library:

1. Create the new `android-support-v7-appcompat` library according to the [instructions](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) on the Android developer Support Library Setup page. ***Note:*** *I had to manually change the* `project.properties` *file to get the new library to compile. Change* `target=android-19` *to* `target=android-21`.
2. Explicitly add this new `android-support-v7-appcompat` library to your troubled project:
   [image: Properties Dialog - Adding library]
   [image: Project Selection Dialog]
3. After that's done the project's properties should look something like this:
   [image: Project Properties]

Now, the project should compile. It's a long way to go, but it worked for me.

---

An interesting side effect of all of this work is that when I created my next project, Eclipse automatically created a new `appcompat_v7` library project, added it to my workspace, and suddenly everything was back to normal. I probably did something different, but I just haven't been able to figure it out what yet. Anyway, I finally got my project to compile and in the process it appears that I reset something in the Eclipse ADT.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

please check whether the version of android you are targeting , do you have the SDK build tools and latest support package ??

If not please go to

> Window>Android sdk manager>

Click the packages for targeting the exact version and update the support if you are targeting the latest

**If none of the above worked then u may have deleted the older sdk build tools in sdk manager after update.Please re-install them and restart eclipse , everything works fine .**

Comment: This sounds more like the real answer to me. Thx Krishna.