# Error:(20) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'

Tags: java, android, resources, android-appcompat

I just add map activity on my project, my project targetsdk android 19, but i got this error

> Error:(20) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

can someone help ?

Lots of problem when develop code using android studio :(.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364682/theme-appcompat-light-darkactionbar-no-resource-found

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900853/no-resource-found-theme-appcompat-light-darkactionbar