# maven android plugin with android support library v7

Tags: java, android, maven

I use maven-android-plugin to build my android app which depends on android support library v4 and v7.
Since I didn't find how to download the whole sdk from developer.android.com, I cnnot use maven android deployee tool to set local repository of android sdk.Thus I want to use the support library that includes in the adt-bundle, below is how I write the dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v7</artifactId>
        <version>18</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/appcompat/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v4</artifactId>
        <version>18</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/appcompat/libs/android-support-v4.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility</artifactId>
        <version>18</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/appcompat.apklib</systemPath>
        <type>apklib</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility</artifactId>
        <version>18</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/appcompat/bin/appcompat.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

The first two is what I wrote at beginning, but maven raised an error:

```
No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
```

Then I added third one. I zip the v7 project and rename to .apklib.But it still does not work.
At last I add the last one,but it does not work either.So how to write a correct pom to fix this?
My system infomation:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Android Platform Version:4.3
Android Maven Plugin:3.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was playing with this I added a `<type>jar</type>` and a `<type>apklib</type>`. I don't remember all the details.

- I did this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18796764/1738827
- My pom file had this:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
      <version>18.0.0</version>
      <type>apklib</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
      <version>18.0.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
     <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
     <version>18.0.0</version>
     <type>aar</type>
 </dependency>
```

I used this and Theme.Appcompat.Light is visible.