# How to include compatibility v7 library maven build?

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

Here is error:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr
```

What is the correct procedure to include a library with resources like this?

I'm trying to include android compatibility v7 library in apk. it compiles but cannot find resources at runtime. I uploaded the compatibility library to my local repo (jar file only), and included it as a maven dependency as follows:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>android.support</groupId>
   <artifactId>compatibility-v13</artifactId>
  <version>23.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Is this enough to get the resources included too?  It just downloads a jar which is all I uploaded to my local repo. How do I include the resources as well in the maven build? If we used the maven sdk deployer instead would including the maven dependency alone be enough? or do I need to create whole project and somehow link to library? This is being built on server so I need pom to pull everything needed.  How do I get it included as library not just jar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I still getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224899/why-am-i-still-getting-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-appcom)

Comment: Well it might, but is including a jar file enough? What I dont understand is including a library with resources in maven build?  Its being done on server.

Comment: So the issue is really if its a library that has XML R. etc what how do I do this. I'm on eclipse with have pop but the whole thing will be built on server. So what is procedure for including library with resources eclipse/maven enviornment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have remaining below *maven* tag in dependency.

please add this:

```
<type>jar</type>
```

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463255/maven-android-plugin-with-android-support-library-v7) for more.