# Android Support Library v7 + Maven + Eclipse: apklib dependency not found in workspace

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-maven-plugin

I'm trying to configure the library v7 support in my project so that it uses ActionBarActivity, thus keeping compliant with some of the Android 2.X versions.

First, follow the documentation from Google and imported the project `android-support-v7-appcompat` as a library in accordance with Section **Adding libraries with resources** on [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html). But this way my **Maven Build failed** because it could not find the dependence of the library in question.

Now, I decided to seek a cleaner solution, keeping my **dependences managed by Maven**. To do this follow the instructions of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18796764/3072570), but using version 19.0.1. This made my Maven Build it were executed successfully, but my **project is not compiling** in my workspace, the following error occurs on first line of my POM:

```
dependency=[com.android.support:appcompat-v7:apklib:19.0.1:compile]not found in workspace
```

My dependencies are as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
    <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
    <version>${com.android.support-version}</version>
    <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
    <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
    <version>${com.android.support-version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

The project in question is on GitHub, if they want to view it: https://github.com/veniltonjr/msplearning

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there is no apklib for com.android.support:appcompat-v7. It only ships as an aar.

Second, that library is not available in maven-central, it ships with the Android SDK.
You need to manually deploy it to your local maven repository.

Though you can use maven-sdk-deployer to construct and deploy the apk to your local folder. But you github project is failing due to missing internal dependencies.
`com.msplearning.android-support-v4:jar:19.1.0`, `com.msplearning:android-support-v7-appcompat:jar:19.1.0`

Comment: Hi @Willian! I uploaded the JAR's on my own Nexus repository as 3rd party artifacts. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using Nexus then there is an even simpler solution. Just create a Nexus repo for your Android SDK artifacts and point it to the location of the maven file repo that the Android SDK constructs. No need to manual deployment then :-)