# Android Lollipop & appcompat v7

Tags: android, gradle

I'm I only one who has this issue: in build.gradle of the application I define these:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    // ...
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

And in the end (after syncing project in android studio 0.8.9, updating to 0.8.13) I'm getting error that some resources aren't found though I've downloaded **ALL** SDK updates?

I'm not using any kind of google play services or etc. Currently the only thing I want is to get "materialized" ActionBar in my Nexus 5 with Lollipop image flashed.

Thanks a lot

Comment: There is no `support-v7` artifact, so that `compile` directive is useless. Beyond that, if you cannot tell us what the exact errors are, it will be difficult for anyone to help you fix those exact errors.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo. I wanted to say support-v4.

Comment: The error is: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'. This error didn't occur whilst I was using API 19

Comment: In which values-folder does this error occur?

Comment: Actually for me it was enough to remove `support-v4` `compile` directive

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in Eclipse where my compile target was not set to api 21. As you have set this I can imagine that your gradle setup does not include the resources.
Maybe that helps:
[How do I add a library (android-support-v7-appcompat) in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025942/how-do-i-add-a-library-android-support-v7-appcompat-in-intellij-idea/18026612#18026612)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I had the same issue in eclipse and what I had to do was:

 1. change the android appcompat-v7 project.properties property "target=android-21"

 2. change your project project.properties property "target=android-21" too.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.
There are 2 things you have to do make sure you are using **build tool 21.1.1**
and please check your `build.gradle` file and change the gradle dependency to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.1'
```

from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
```

Make sure your sdk is updated to version 21 and in your gradle compileSdkVersion is 21

I hope this will work for you.