# Faced with Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'

Tags: android

I am stuck with a problem, I have created a basic *hello world* app following official  [website](http://developer.android.com)! now when I try running the app I see error as

***error:***

```
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '

Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.   
Resourse: styles.xml    
path: /Test_1/res/values-v14    
Location : line 8   
Type: Android AAPT Problem
```

I tried adding `v7 library` by `[Project ->Properties->Android]` and click on "Add" but I do not see any thing in the resulted project Selection pop up. I see error in `(appcompat-v7 ->res->values-large-v14->themes_base.xml`

code:

```
<style name="Theme.Base.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge"
       parent="Theme.Base.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge.Base" />

<style name="Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge"
       parent="Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge.Base" />
```

My target sdk is `API 19` and `min sdk version is 7`, I am not sure how to deal with this. could you please help.

Comment: Do you have v7 library in workspace? if not import it to workspce and then try to add to library.

Comment: Seems like you're missing `support-v7-appcompat` library -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025942/how-do-i-add-a-library-android-support-v7-appcompat-in-intellij-idea

Answer (score 3):

It looks like all **Theme.Base**.xxxx was renamed to **Base.Theme**.xxxx

Try to use `Base.Theme.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge`