# Android, Eclipse in Mac

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi I am trying to make an android app on my Mac but am getting the following error when creating a new project

[2015-03-09 18:33:06 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /Users/shareennainar/Documents/workspace/appcompat_v7/bin/jarlist.cache

any help will be appreciated

Comment: You should mark any question as a correct if my answer helped to you feel free to mark mine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

> Project->Properties->Java build path. On the "Order and Export" tab, make sure you have checked all the libraries the project is referring to in your case appcompat_v7

Be sure you have `android:minSdkVersion="14"`, else change it to 14 and do Project -> Clean

Also you can take a look -> [this](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/15/really-blank-activity-why-appcompat-shoved-down-your-throat.html) or [this](http://arul-khairullah.blogspot.com.es/2014/11/android-appcompatv7-errors-when-update.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need specifically use eclipse I encourage you to use Android Studio. I changed from eclipse to Android Studio and I think it's one of the best choices I did in my work.

P.S: That error looks like you don't have the appcompat library installed in your project. Are you using gradle? if so try to add it using the following line.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
```

If you don't use gradle you must add it manually.

EDIT: Here you can see how to import different libraries into your android project. 
http://android-er.blogspot.com.es/2013/12/create-library-project-with-appcompat.html

Comment: I editted my answer ;) If it's useful please mark it as resolved thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is the library is compiled in 1.7 and eclipse is trying to to load it on 1.6. I updated my Java but its still not working I also get a warning when i create an Android project. "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0"

Comment: Are you using Gradle?

Comment: Look into this post is a non-gradle solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025942/how-do-i-add-a-library-android-support-v7-appcompat-in-intellij-idea

Answer (score 0):

This error means you're trying to load a Java "class" file that was compiled with a *newer* version of Java than you have installed.

For example, your .class file could have been compiled for JDK 7, and you're trying to run it with JDK 6. To solve this, you may take one of these solutions:

- In Eclipse's menu

  > Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler

  Check "Configure Project Specific Settings".
- Upgrade your Java runtime or
  Recompile the class if you have the source, using your local Java compiler (if you have one).

  javac FileName.java