# Android support Library v7 appcompat

Tags: android, android-layout, intellij-idea, android-support-library, android-appcompat

i've got a problem with the Android v7 Support Library.
I want to use Android Material Design on Android Version 4 and above, so I have to use the Support Library v7 appcompat.
For Development i'm using IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4

The way i included the Library:
[image: Project Structure Libs]

[image: Project Structure Modules]

If i compile and run my Project, this error occures:

```
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4cdab20)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.package.application/de.package.application.activities.DrawerActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:816)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at de.package.application.activities.DrawerActivity.onCreate(DrawerActivity.java:82)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ ... 11 more
07-15 05:18:08.636    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-15 05:18:08.640    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-15 05:18:08.640    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
07-15 05:18:08.640    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
07-15 05:18:08.640    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ ... 24 more
07-15 05:18:08.640    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr
07-15 05:18:08.640    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:191)
07-15 05:18:08.640    1675-1675/de.package.application W/System.err﹕ ... 27 more
```

The Xml-Document, where the error occures:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:background="#DDD">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I'm working on this for hours.
I hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance

(Sorry for spelling- and grammatical errors)

**Edit:**

I added the libs like described in the other Question.
I have it now like this:
[image: Project Structure Library Module]

[image: Project Structure Main Module]

But still the same errors :l

Comment: Can you show your gradle build file ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in your build.gradle(Module:app) dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```

and then sync your project

it will add the library automatically

Comment: The last version is 22.2.0

Comment: Thanks, I converted my Project to a gradle-project, and added these line. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this one:

[How do I add a library (android-support-v7-appcompat) in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025942/how-do-i-add-a-library-android-support-v7-appcompat-in-intellij-idea)

There's both With/Without Gradle solutions there.

Comment: I tried it, but it does not helped. Maybe i've done something wrong.