# How to add textDirection support to API 8?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-appcompat

I want to create an Android app using `API 8`

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
```

I have a `EditText` control in which I want to type in right-to-left mode.
There is a new property called [textDirection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:textDirection) which is support in `API 17` and higher. But I want to know if there is anyway to make my app supports this property. I heard about some *appcompat* things but I couldn't figure out if [android-support-v7-appcompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025942/how-do-i-add-a-library-android-support-v7-appcompat-in-intellij-idea) has something to do with it.

Will `android-support-v7-appcompat` solve my problem? cause I tried that and also [Adding android.support.v4 to your Android application in IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.in-nomine.org/2012/02/26/adding-android-support-v4-to-your-android-application-in-intellij-idea/). but none solved my problem.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Why on gods green earth would you want to go trough any trouble to support android 2.2? At most [0.2% of all android users are on 2.2](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). Of course you are free to do it, but I'm very curious why :-) It's like making programs backwards compatible for windows 95

Comment: @TimCastelijns Even if I want to make it to API 15, I will still have the same problem.