# Trying to use maven with android eclipse project not working?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

This is the first time I've used maven, I am trying to integrate **zopim sdk** and I followed the tutorial and converted my project to a maven project and added the repository and dependencies, but now eclipse does not compile and gives me the following error  :

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Missing artifact com.android.support:appcompat-v7:jar:23.0.0    pom.xml /4SaleApp   line 2  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.android.support:design:jar:23.0.0  pom.xml /4SaleApp   line 2  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:jar:23.0.0 pom.xml /4SaleApp   line 2  Maven Dependency Problem
```

What should I do ?

**EDIT**

my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>4SaleApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>4SaleApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>chatsdk-repo</id>
            <name>Chat SDK Repo</name>
            <url>https://zendesk.artifactoryonline.com/zendesk/repo</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zopim.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <type>aar</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: More info required. Maybe share your pom.xml file ?

Comment: @Fido : please view my edit.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a conflicting issue when changing from Gradle to Maven. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025942/how-do-i-add-a-library-android-support-v7-appcompat-in-intellij-idea) questions provides a lot more info on the issue.

But it looks like you are missing the android support dependencies in the pom. Maybe try adding the missing support libraries to the pom. For example as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18588292/1457059) for  `appcompat-v7`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>android.support</groupId>
    <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
    <version>${compatibility.version}</version>
    <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>android.support</groupId>
    <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
    <version>${compatibility.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have tried it but still does not work and give me the same errors