# android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar import Error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

***import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;[eclipse]***

Error:
*The import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar collides with another import statement*

lib:android-support-v7-appcompat.jar

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

**Any link to download android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar JAR only??**

Comment: The error seems to suggest, or really is very clear, that you have another import that causes collision? On a side note, can you switch to Android Studio?

Comment: FYI , Moved to Android studio .

Comment: this link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025942/how-do-i-add-a-library-android-support-v7-appcompat-in-intellij-idea or you can use with gradle dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
} and also you need to set minSdkVersion 21.0

Comment: No , i need the solution for eclipse :(

Answer (score 0):

Check your SDK Manager,if you are using an old version of the Support Library. The Toolbar widget did not get introduced until v21, you are using v20. Upgrade to latest.

And add that support lib project as a lib project to your project.