# Runtime DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY excpetion

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I'm following [this](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) tutorial from  and I'm facing with a strange problem.

It doesn't matter what's in my `DrawerLayout`, but if its `layout_height` or `layout_width` are set to anything other than hardcoded number, it throws this runtime exception.

I've seeing plenty of reports of this error thrown when trying to render an output in the Graphical Layout tool, but couldn't find any on a runtime error.

I have the latest support library, updated just now to version `21.0.2`

I would like to avoid hardcoding my height and width if possible.

The beginning of the file looks like this. This way, it crushes.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

and the stacktrace is

```
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254): Process: com.lablabla.homedestroyer, PID: 26254
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:814)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1141)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
12-04 00:57:51.051: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

If it has to be hardcoded, what's the best way to make it "right" for various screen sizes?

Comment: This Link helped me solve this issue.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17995545/3033942

Comment: Did you specify parameters like in here? https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html Mainly order of layouts and gravity of the drawer?

Answer (score 3):

Try overriding the DrawerLayout's on measure method

```
public class CustomDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout {

public CustomDrawerLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found putting `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before `setContent()` could solve this in my case.